# Extracting text from a variable containing HTML

Tags: javascript, innertext

I have a variable that contains the HTML of an ordered list of list-items of text, all within a div.

When I console.log that variable I get the nice piece oh HTML output.

I want to extract that text because chrome storage isn't allowing me to save a variable containing HTML for some reason.

I have tried variable.innerText with no luck. Any idea?

Comment: Post a jsfiddl.net with your code and I will try to help you

Comment: @user1477388 It's a mess I know, I have no idea how to use jquery. http://jsfiddle.net/vL5UH/  I'm trying to cut down a wikipedia API thing then save a string.

Comment: @Ian have tried and failed with .textContent

Comment: Can't really test your code since it's dependent on your server.  If you can somehow recreate it for me on jsfiddle so I can test it, maybe I can help.

Comment: when you say chrome storage do you mean localstorage? If so you should JSON.stringify your text before you store it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store your HTML and retrieve it as-is, you could encode it using Javascript's `escape` function on the innerHTML attribute, and then decode it using `unescape`, although these functions are deprecated since ECMAScript 3.
A more modern way would be to encode/decode it using base64 encoding (and the encoded string would be shorter).